# Fetch chunked content with Google AppScript UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, chunked-encoding

Trying to get chunked content with [Google AppScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions:true});
```

Unfortunately, it does not handle it well and stops after first chunk or somewhere between.

Here are the HTTP response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers:
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 26 Oct 2018 11:15:24 GMT
x-request-id: 2lgi8mvh6onm5jrvf8000tl1
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Does `UrlFetchApp` even support chunked responses? If not, is there any alternative?

Comment: HTTP/2 doesn't support chunked-encoding. If the chunks aren't sent async, the only other limitation is the 50MB/call quota. What's the estimated total size of the chunks, you're about to receive?

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed it is a quota limit rather than an issues with chunked responses!

Comment: @I'-'I Would it actually mean that google by these limitations is discouraging using any third party services in favor of google services? 50MB is not a lot of data, especially when building some connectors for data studio.